# Finding $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ of a uniformally distributed continuous variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation, uniform-distribution

I am having a problem finding E(X), Var(X) of a uniformly distributed variable. Can someone please help or correct me. The question and solution is below. Thanks
[image]

Comment: By the way, the last equality is false: $P(b<X<2b)\ne0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in the calculation of the expected value. We have that
$$
\int_b^{4b}x\frac1{3b}\mathrm dx=\frac1{3b}\biggl[\frac{x^2}{\color{red}2}\biggr]_b^{4b}=\frac{5b}{\color{red}2}.
$$
This mistake makes the calculation of the variance also wrong.